# Booking/Reservation system

Tags: entries

I'm about to start building out a site that requires a booking system to be setup within it. The site owner should be able to set availability (days and times with time-frames) and allow the visitors to book/reserve available services within the available time-frames and make a payment.

Any suggestions on how one might go about this? I know the request is pretty vague, just looking for some broad strokes to help me kick off in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as 'setting availablity' goes, one could choose to make a 'services' section with a Matrix field that contains a DateTimeField. That way, the client can create a new Matrix Block for each available time span. The {% cache %} tag will help you in speeding this up on the frontend.

For booking, you could:

- A: Make a 'bookings' section, with a related content field 'service'. Fill this section with a [frontend Entry form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entry-form), set post and expiry dates to the time span of the visitor's choice. You could now display a list of bookings on the frontend (behind a login), or have your client manage bookings through the CP's content tab.
- B: Make a plugin to handle bookings. This would be my preferred approach.

To handle payments, you could use an existing plugin ([Charge](http://squarebit.co.uk/plugins/charge), for example) or build your own.